# How to get the default DNS server of a NetAdapter without resetting the addresses on the Adapter?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am trying to get the IP addresses for the default DNS Servers for a NetAdapter.

```
$IFIndex = (Get-NetAdapter).IFIndex
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $IFIndex -ResetServerAddresses 
$DNSServers = (Get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $IFIndex).ServerAddresses
```

I would like to get the defaults without needing to reset to the defaults. Is the response from the DHCP server cached somewhere? In lieu of that, I think I could directly DHCP server directly instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is cached for each interface in DhcpNameServer in `HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\`

```
$InstanceID = (Get-NetAdapter).InstanceID
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\$InstanceID" -Name DhcpNameServer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DhcpNameServer
```